# Passing a parameter to a getter/setter?

Tags: c#, parameter-passing, getter-setter

I have a subclass passing a parameter to the super class like so:

```
public int CountMenuItems(List<string> Items)
{    
    //Returns sub-class total item count
    return Items.Count;
}
```

All my sub-classes will be using the code above.

Now, I have this in the super class to:

```
public int Iterator
{
    get
    {
        return iterator;
    }
    set
    {
        iterator = value;
        if (iterator > <Count list here>  - 1) iterator = 0;
        if (iterator < 0) iterator = <Count list here>  - 1;
    }
}
```

I want to get the parameter value from the CountMenuItems() method and place it into the getter/setter.

How would I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What about declaring another property in your super class that is the List and then referencing it there?

```
public int Iterator
{
    get
    {

        return iterator;
    }
    set
    {
        iterator = value;
        if (iterator > Items.Count  - 1) iterator = 0;
        if (iterator < 0) iterator = Items.Count  - 1;
    }
}

public List<string> Items
{
    get; set;
}
```

Just set the property in your super class from your subclass before you reference Iterator.

```
var yourClass = new YourClass();
yourClass.Items = items;
yourClass.Iterator = 500;
Console.Write(yourClass.Iterator.ToString());
```

Another option would be to create a new constructor that takes List item as a parameter and set your property in the constructor.